# Error: Keys not exchanged when calling await ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'})

Tags: react-native, authentication, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I am trying to connect my React Native app to MetaMask with
MetamaskSDK, but I am getting the error "Error: Keys not exchanged"
when calling await ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'}).
The connection request gets stuck on the phrase "Connecting to
Metamask". This happens before Metamask shows a connection request
popup with my application data. It is very strange that this error does not
occur on every connection.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
const MMSDK = new MetaMaskSDK({
    openDeeplink: (link) => {
        Linking.openURL(link);
    },
    timer: BackgroundTimer,
    dappMetadata: {
        name: 'dapp',
        url: 'https://dapp.com',
    },
});
export const ethereum = MMSDK.getProvider();
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
export const ConnectWallet = () => {
    const [walletAddress, setWalletAddress] = useState('');
    const [chain, setChain] = useState('');
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({
        token: null,

        userId: null,
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        ethereum.on('chainChanged', setChain);
        ethereum.on('accountsChanged', handleAccountsChanged);
        return () => {
            ethereum.removeListener('chainChanged', setChain);
            ethereum.removeListener('accountsChanged', handleAccountsChanged);
        };
    }, []);
    const handleAccountsChanged = async (accounts) => {
        setWalletAddress(accounts?.[0] || '');
        onLogin();
    };
    const onConnect = async () => {
        try {
            if (!isAuthenticated && ethereum.isMetaMask) {
                const result = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
                console.log('RESULT', result?.[0]);
                setWalletAddress(result?.[0]);
            }
            else {
                console.log("It looks like you don't have the Metamask App installed yet");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    };
    const onLogin = async () => {
        try {
            const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
            const [account] = accounts;
            if (!account) {
                setIsAuthenticated(false);
                return;
            }
            const createNonce = await fetch(`${url}/nonce/${account}`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            });
            const res = await createNonce.json();
            if (res) {
                const signature = await provider.getSigner().signMessage(res.nonce);
                const response = await fetch(`${url}/user/`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        walletAddress: account,
                        signature: signature,
                    }),
                });
                const data = await response.json();
                setUserDetails({
                    token: data.token,
                    userId: data.id,
                });
                setIsAuthenticated(true);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    };
    return (
        <View>
            <Button onPress={onConnect} />
        </View>
    );
}
```